# Sources on Hamilton's Discovery of Quaternions

Tags: math-history, quaternions

This is a strange question and I'm not sure where to put it; I'm currently writing an essay for a history of maths course, and I've chosen the topic of Hamilton's discovery of the quaternions. I assume that after he discovered them, he would have published a paper explaining his thought processes etc., but every paper I can find is on the applications of quaternions rather than their discovery.

I know he experimented with triplets before he realized that he needed a fourth dimension, and I'm looking for his papers that document this.

Any recommendations would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: While most of [this paper](http://math.berkeley.edu/~lam/html/quat.ps) is not dedicated to the discovery itself, I sure found the description and context of the discovery very good. [Altmann's book](http://www.amazon.com/Rotations-Quaternions-Double-Groups-Mathematics/dp/0486445186) also has a great description of the discovery.

Answer (score 6):

See [Hamilton's Research on Quaternions](http://www.maths.tcd.ie/pub/HistMath/People/Hamilton/Quaternions.html).

Comment: This story is told by van der Waerden (with the same references as in the link above) in [A History of Algebra From al-Kwarizmi to Emmy Noether](http://www.amazon.com/History-Algebra-From-al-Khwarizmi-Noether/dp/3642516017/ref=sr_1_6?ie=UTF8&qid=1395323664&sr=8-6&keywords=van+der+waerden+algebra), pp. 179-183.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to examine the possibility that this was discovered earlier by the Spanish mathematician and banker [Olinde Rodrigues](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olinde_Rodrigues) in 1840.